# Spring Boot Application Tests with H2 Database and Flyway Fails to Seed

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I have an application I am trying to test using H2.

Here's my application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:appdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:appdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
    user: "root"
    password: ""
    locations: classpath:/db/migration, classpath:/db/seed
```

Flyway successfully runs the migrations (or at least it appears to), and the tables are created successfully as evidenced by the startup:

```
2018-04-03 08:47:42.956  INFO 17980 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 0
...
```

It even seems my seeds are "working":

```
2018-04-03 08:47:43.162  INFO 17980 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" with repeatable migration Seed sample
```

It tells me it worked:

```
2018-04-03 08:47:43.188  INFO 17980 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 18 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.283s)
```

My SQL files are written in PostgreSQL's SQL dialect. However, I've read that leaving hibernate on H2Dialect is fine.

When the tests go to run, it appears by the time the tests finish running there's nothing in the database, so the tests fail.

My thoughts are that H2 is closing out the DB before the tests finish, but that seems strange to me. The seeds and the tables are working correctly.

Is there anything I can do to verify everything is working here, or options I have not yet tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Flyway schemas to your database name:

```
flyway:
  schemas: appdb
```